# QuickSearch not working

Tags: joomla, quicksearch

I'm dealing with a system where the Quick Search box is not working.  Using the browser dev tools shows ajax requests being sent but receiving a '406 Not acceptable' error.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406 this relates to content negotiation.

The AJAX URL is:

```
https://example.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/rest&entity=contact&action=getquick&json={"name":"a","field_name":"","table_name":"cc"}
```

and the content negotiation headers in the request are:

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
```

This matches what I see on another system that is working normally.

This is CiviCRM 5.5.2 on Joomla 3.8.13

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does the webserver support compression? Might be a disabled module (e.g. mod_gzip in apache). The Accept-Encoding suggests only compressed data is accepted.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried changing the Accept-Encoding header to various things including * and all fail.  On a different system I've also tried the same changes and I can't get that to fail so I'm wondering with it really is a 406 or something else that is wrongly identifying.

Comment: If you're seeing a 406 status, I do think it'll be coming from your webserver or Joomla and not CiviCRM. CiviCRM's HTTP response code vocab doesn't include 406 AFAIK. Any of those `Accept*` headers could trigger a 406 if the application couldn't satisfy them.

Comment: Maybe a .htaccess file that is weird. It's possible for mod_rewrite for example to be told to return 406 for certain url patterns. Or maybe mod_security blocking it and returning 406.